# join query in one sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is my query result where one doesn't have group name. I want to get a group name by using parent_id.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [groupName] => pizza
            [Parent_ID] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupName] => 
            [Parent_ID] => 63
        )
}
```

Here is my table structure

**Category**

```
1.id
2.parent_id (if id got sub category than id's value enter into parent_id field)
```

**Category Group**

```
1.id
2.name
```

**Join table**

```
1.id
2.cat_id
3.group name
```

please help me

here is my sql statement

```
$sql1 = "SELECT gn.group_name AS groupName, 
c.parent_id AS Parent_ID

                    FROM 
                        LEFT JOIN res_category c ON c.id=p.category_id
                        LEFT JOIN res_category sc ON c.parent_id=sc.id 
                        LEFT JOIN res_cat_category_group cgn ON c.id=cgn.category_id
 LEFT JOIN res_category_group gn ON gn.id=cgn.cat_group_id ";
```

Comment: what is your attempted query ?

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/snQCods3EQ5MpmnX/127.0.0.1

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this?

```
select * from category a, category_group b, join_table c where c.cat_id = a.id and c.group_name = b.name
```

Comment: Suggesting implicit JOIN as a solution is too outdated. Explicit joins (better and efficient solution) have been there for 20+ years